# Org Agenda missing past TODO items in Org 9.1

Tags: org-agenda

Org-mode's agenda view is behaving differently for me based on whether I use the Org-mode 8.2.10 that came with my Emacs or 9.1.1 as installed from Elpa. Specifically, on 8.2.10, the default "week" agenda view includes TODO items that are past due, but in 9.1.1, it does not. I am using the exact same configuration in either case. My `init.el` is [here](https://gist.github.com/inducer/eb020a55f13dfa7ea24bfb8a34710400) in case that helps. I would be grateful for any hints as to what might be causing this difference in behavior.

For example, today (2017-09-24), the following overdue todo item would be included in 8.x, but not in 9.x:

```
* TODO review code

DEADLINE: <2017-09-05>
```

I am using Emacs 25.2.2 from Debian.

Comment: I suggest you add an example of a todo item that "past due" and that behaves differently in the two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you remove the space between the heading and the
deadline.  A question about this was recently [asked on the Org
list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-09/msg00077.html).  To quote Eric Fraga quoting the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-scheduling):

```
As the manual says:

     A timestamp may be preceded by special keywords to facilitate
     planning.  Both the timestamp and the keyword have to be positioned
     immediately after the task they refer to.

I guess immediately means not even a blank line.
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. What makes this confusing is that it seems the processing of `DEADLINE` is inconsistent between past-due and currently-due events. The former do not seem to enforce the no-spaces rule, while the latter do.

Comment: Yeah, that inconsistency is confusing and I think it should be
addressed, but I'm not able to reproduce it on Org's maint (d40deb696)
or master (405555ec5) branch.  Could you email the Org list with a
minimal example that triggers the issue?